# Why does curl not work with non-default network interface in CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, routing, curl

`curl` can use non-default network interface with its `--interface` option theoretically. However, in practise it doesn't work.
I have 2 network interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`. Each one is connected to Internet via its own router and uses DHCP for autoconfiguration. Lets say `eth0` IP is `ip0` and `eth1` IP is `ip1`.
So, I set `eth0` as default connection via `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and run following command:

```
curl --url "http://ip-api.com/json"
```

I get JSON reply where I see that actual external IP is `ip0`. Now I set `eth1` instead of `eth0` as default interface, and the same command returns me `ip1`.

Now I set `eth0` as default IP again and run following command:

```
curl --url "http://ip-api.com/json" --interface "eth0"
```

No problems, it returns `ip0`.

And finally:

```
curl --url "http://ip-api.com/json" --interface "eth1"
```

results in following error:

> curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

As we can see from previous test (where `eth1` was default interface), `eth1` has not issues. It is very reliable wired connection actually, so the issue is not related to any network stability problems.

My routing table follows:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.85.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
192.168.182.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         192.168.182.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.85.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth1
```

Can anyone explain why curl doesn't work with non-default interface?

Comment: Please show you routing table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The --interface options is used to figure determine what address on the system will be used as the source IP.  It doesn't magically change anything about routing.

A typical system will only have a single default gateway.  Naively connecting two ports two different networks using only DHCP simply is not going to give you a working multi-homed system.  One of the interfaces will work to connect to the internet and one will only work for the subnet.  Trying to bind like you have done is going to just send packets through the wrong router.

On Linux it is possible to get this working, but it requires multiple route tables, and rules to define which table to use.  See this howto.

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html

Comment: I can confirm that above commands started to work as expected after I added 2 custom routing tables (one per network interface) and specific correct default gateway for each custom table.